# Scaling this python script for multiple stocks

Tags: python, pandas, finance, stock

First off, thank you for taking the time to help me. We are using this python script that pulls data from Yahoo for a given time period.

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web

style.use('ggplot')
start = dt.datetime (2007,1,1)
end = dt.datetime(2022,1,31)

df = web.DataReader('AAPL','yahoo', start, end)
df.to_csv('AAPl.csv')
```

The code above grabs the data we need from Yahoo for the AAPL stock for the dates we set, then it creates a CSV for that stock. The problem we are running into is that we have 5000 different stocks we need to do this for. We have a CSV file with all the different tickers we need to run this program over. How can we modify our code to run over the different stocks from our CSV? Instead of us having to run this program manually 5000 times.

Comment: why is this call `style.use('ggplot')` part of the process?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to write the intermediate dataframes (for individual stock symbols) to file.  Try something like:

```
tickers = pd.read_csv(r'path_to/symbols.csv')['symbol_column_name'].values
full_df = pd.DataFrame({})
for ticker in tickers:
    df = web.DataReader(ticker,'yahoo', start, end)
    full_df = pd.concat((full_df, df))
#Now write merged table to file
full_df.to_csv('my_output_table.csv')
```

Comment: This created one file, my_output_table.csv. Maybe I'm not understanding, but shouldn't it produce seperate CSVs for each of the stocks listed in the ticker CSV?

Comment: Alternatively, 1 file is fine if there is a column indicating which ticker the data belongs too

Comment: Never mind! I got it! I added df.insert(6,"Ticker",ticker) below the df = web.DataReader